# Ruby instance_exec / instance_eval with arguments

Tags: ruby, arguments, instance-eval

I'm trying to dynamically call a method given in a string using parameters given in the same string, I'm getting stuck on supplying the parameters though...

I currently have:

```
query = Query.new

while true
  input = gets.split(%r{[/[[:blank:]]/,]})
  puts (query.instance_exec(*input.drop(1)) { |x|
    instance_eval input.at(0)
  })
end
```

So the method name is input(0) and the arguments to this method are in the rest of input.
Is there any way to call this method with those parameters?

Comment: What does your input string look like? I only ask because your regex looks a bit odd.

Comment: The string looks like `method_name paramList` where paramList is a variable number of parameters separated by either commas, whitespace or a mix of both. So the regex should decompose this into an array of the form [method_name, param1, param2, ...]. PS: it should actually be `%r{[/[[:blank:]]/,]+}` I fixed that in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `send`. Its first argument will be the method, and the rest will be passed to that method.

```
query = Query.new
puts query.send(*gets.split(/\s+/)) while true
```

- You can use `while` modifier.
- Your regex looks complicated. I made it look simple.
- Don't forget to use the splat operator `*`, which decomposes an array.